# Is the child correct when saying "the balloon is flying on my hand"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

I taught my child a lot of expressions to a point that he can create his own words.

Today he said "**the balloon is flying on my hand**" when he was holding a balloon by its neck and it was swaying back and forth when it was triggered by some wind.

I have never used the preposition "**on**" like that before, he must have chosen that preposition based on his own judgement and experience.

Is the child correct when saying "**the balloon is flying on my hand**" in this situation?

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. Since the balloon doesn't have "wings", he can't say it's ***flapping** (about) in/on his hand*, and highly metaphoric ***trying to fly*** might be a bit *too* creative. Or maybe not. I certainly wouldn't see it as a situation where there's any reason to "correct" the child - if anything, he's doing quite well on the "creative use of language" front.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, what about "She stood on the clifftop, her grey hair flying in the wind." from the dictionary. Certainly, her grey hair still sticking on her head as it flies. "fly" can mean "to be blown around in the wind".

Comment: Sure. So why are you asking about the usage here? For such an obscure context, it's really a bit pointless asking what's the "right" preposition to link whatever verb is chosen to the speaker's hand.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, because you said "the balloon doesn't have wings" so I reckoned you meant "only things with wings can fly". But I didn't read your words carefully. Ignore it! It's better say "it's flapping on his hand"

Comment: The two elements "flying" and "hand" don't really go together very well (something can fly ***to*** or ***from*** a hand, but they're both "instantaneous actions", not "continuous activities"). Which verb to use *(**flying, flapping, waving, swinging, swishing, flailing,...**)* is a matter of choice - though I'd be very surprised (not to mention *impressed!* :) to hear a young child come out with ***flailing*** here. And arguably the preposition ***on*** is just "the best of a bad bunch".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, in https://www.lincolnil.gov/, they said "...the red flag is flying on the pole...." (https://www.lincolnil.gov/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=355&Itemid=424) and here "The Batman flag is flying on the pole in the front yard" (http://moreclaremore.com/2015/07/25/claremore-past-a-green-country-potpourri/)
How would you explain these?

Comment: I don't see anything to "explain" here. You can [*fly a flag* or *fly a balloon*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fly+a+flag%2Cfly+a+balloon&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfly%20a%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfly%20a%20balloon%3B%2Cc0). But you don't call it "flying a flag" if you're just waving a little pennant in your hand - that's ***waving** a flag / pennant*. And there's simply no idiomatically established version of anything like that for ***balloons*** (as a verb for what the *person* is doing, OR what the *balloon* is doing).